# Chrome update on 6th May broke Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

There was an update of Chrome on Android phones on 6th May, and it broke the functioning of Webview.

Certain parts of the webview would not load and the screen would become blank in that area. Observations -

1. It could be any arbitrary part of the webview and the shape of the area is always rectangular / a combination of rectangles.
2. Clicking on the area renders the text, but not in all the cases.
3. Disabling Chrome solves the problem. But we obviously can't ask our users to disable their web browser.
4. Uninstalling updates to Chrome works, but we need to additionally prevent Chrome's auto-update so that it doesn't revert to the latest version and break the Webview again. The trouble is, not all Android versions provide the option to restrict auto-updates to a particular app, and switching it off from Play Store switches it off for ALL the apps, which is not what we want.
5. It mostly (but not always) happens only in cases where the Webview is nested inside a Scrollview or NestedScrollView.

We have nearly 2,00,000 active users on Android, and have got a spate of bad reviews and low ratings due to this issue in the last week or so.

Even last year there was an update that had screwed up the caching of Webviews.